# Reactjs ahooks useRequest: options.staleTime is preventing manual refresh and refresh via refreshDeps

Tags: reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-marco-2tk4xd?file=/App.tsx

In the demo, the article will be be considered old 5 seconds after it was last refreshed, and will be refreshed again the next time you hide/show the article.

However, this also means that if you hit the refresh button within 5 seconds of the last refresh, the article won't be refreshed. Is there anyway to fix this with what ahooks provides, without implementing my own manual refresh (by detecting changes with `useEffect` and calling `clearCache`)?

Code (also in the sandbox):

```
import { useBoolean } from "ahooks";
import Mock from "mockjs";
import React from "react";
import { useRequest } from "ahooks";

async function getArticle(): Promise<{ data: string; time: number }> {
  console.log("cacheKey-staleTime");
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        data: Mock.mock("@paragraph"),
        time: new Date().getTime()
      });
    }, 1000);
  });
}

const Article = () => {
  const { data, loading, refresh } = useRequest(getArticle, {
    cacheKey: "staleTime-demo",
    staleTime: 5000
  });
  if (!data && loading) {
    return <p>Loading</p>;
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={refresh}>
        refresh
      </button>
      <p>Background loading: {loading ? "true" : "false"}</p>
      <p>Latest request time: {data?.time}</p>
      <p>{data?.data}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default () => {
  const [state, { toggle }] = useBoolean();
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => toggle()}>
        show/hidden
      </button>
      {state && <Article />}
    </div>
  );
};
```